# Implicit typecasting not working if passing integer value as argument in java

Tags: java, byte, implicit

In the following code , implicit typecasting for an integer value 9 take place and assigned to variable of byte datatype which is of size 8 bits.

```
class Demo1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
    {

    byte b=9;
    System.out.println(b);

    }

}
```

The code happily compiled and executed .

but when i wrote the following code it gave me compilation error

```
class Demo2 
{
   void func1(byte b)
    {
        System.out.println(b);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Demo2 d1=new Demo2();
       d1.func1(9);
    }
}
```

please explain me why  implicit (auto typecasting) is not taking place in the latter code?

Thank you  all in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Because `byte` (8 bits) can hold less information than `int` (32 bits), so the compiler will not automatically cast `int` to `byte` because you can lose information in the process. For example:

```
    int a = 150;
    byte b = (byte) a;
    System.out.println(b);
```

This will print `-106` because `150` is out of byte range (-128 - 127).

Compiler needs you to manually cast `int` to `byte` to make sure this is not an error and that you understand the implications of the cast.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code like below so that you don't get possible loss of precision error.

This will make compiler to understand that you know you are going to lose precision.

```
void func1(int i)
    {
        byte b = (byte)i;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Comment: You're casting byte to byte. Also this is not [downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting).

Comment: alternate to this is , i can typecast the arguement i am passing as byte in the function call in the main() method ( so my func1() remain intact ) . but this is not my question . i am asking why the value assigned to byte b is accepted in the class Demo1 but the same is not being accepted when i am passing it as argument to a function in class Demo2.

Comment: sorry , i forget to add alternate code line for class Demo2: `d1.func1((byte)9);`