# How does narrowing work in method invocation in Java?

Tags: java, narrowing

Why this is giving the compile time error?
2 is constant at compile time, therefore narrowing should be allowed here since 2 is in range of byte.

```
public class Test {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ForTest test=new ForTest();
    test.sum(1, 2); //compile time error here

}

}
class ForTest
{

public int sum(int a,byte b)
{
    System.out.println("method byte");
    return a+b;
}
}
```

The error is: 
The method sum(int,byte) in the type ForTest is not applicable for the arguements (int,int).

Edit: I think the answer lies here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3 but I am not getting it :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442782/implicit-typecasting-not-working-if-passing-integer-value-as-argument-in-java

Comment: At least there are byte literals now to mitigate the problem (I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to distinguish between *assignment conversion* and *method invocation conversion*.

**Narrowing Primitive Conversion**

First of all, look at [JLS §5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the *narrowing primitive conversions*:
>
> - [...]
> - int to byte, short, or char
>
> [...]

Note, that this only explains the mechanism but not the places where such conversions are allowed or not.

**Assignment Conversion**

Next, look at [JLS §5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> [...]
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
>
> [...]

This clearly describes that in the assignment `byte b = 2` the narrowing conversion from type *int* to type *byte* is allowed.

**Method Invocation Conversion**

However, when reading [JLS §5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) you will not read anything about a narrowing conversion. So the compiler is doing a correct job.

Answer (score 3):

This is because 2 is interpreted as an int, which cannot be implicitly converted into a byte.

Your choices are either to change the method signature to (`int a, int b`), or to explicitly do a casting: `test.sum(1, (byte)2)`

Comment: it can be implicitly converted to a byte in assignment, but this is an exception. e.g. `byte b = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't type cast `int` to `byte` implicitly.
Call method as:

```
sum(1, (byte)2);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer:**

The java language specification says that when looking for candidate matches for function calls, after the candidates have been found based upon the name of the function, and the number of actual vs. formal parameters, it eventually arrives at [phase 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3).

"If m is not a generic method, then m is applicable by loose invocation if, for 1 ≤ i ≤ n, either ei is compatible in a loose invocation context with Fi or ei is not pertinent to applicability."

Evidently, when it arrive at the second actual parameter, it is deciding that an 'int' is not compatible in a 'loose invocation context' with 'byte'.  Therefore it rejects the one and only matching candidate it found in phase 1.

I'm unable to find a formal definition of "loose invocation" in the JLS.

Thanks to VikasMangal and KisHanarsecHaGajjar for pointing out the stupidity of my original answer which is repeated below for eternal shame.

**My original answers the comments refer to is below.**

Java spec section [5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) says you *should* be able to do this.

Additionally in section 5.2 on assignment of constants it says

"In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:

A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable."

However, the compiler seems to be going it's own way.

Comment: can you provide reference link ?

Comment: fixed, have to scroll down to 5.1.3 though, should be easy to find. -- edited, nevermind, found the anchor.

Comment: HAH, totally correct!  I skipped that word in the sentence expecting them to be in largest to smallest order.

Comment: @caskey according to your argument, 2 is representable in byte than it should automatically type cast here.
for eg:
byte b=2; is allowed since 2 is int and is representable in byte

Comment: No, the problem is that I'm quoting from the java language spec which regards assignment of a constant to a variable of narrower type.  This instance is the compiler in which case it's the compiler spec that I should have been concerning myself with.

Comment: To be clear, he is expecting a narrowing of not a constant but a "Lexical Literal" which I don't see any specific treatment of in the compiler spec.

Comment: I think the answer lies here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3

but I am not getting it :(

Comment: No, method invocation is a runtime concept, this is a compile time error where the compiler is finding an expression it can't match up dispatch for.  As an experiment I believe if you were to assign '2' to an int right above then pass it in, you would compile fine but run the risk of a narrowing error.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2 is the section with the rules for matching, it's thick.

Comment: Further reading shows:  "If m is not a generic method, then m is applicable by loose invocation if, for 1 ≤ i ≤ n, either ei is compatible in a loose invocation context with Fi or ei is not pertinent to applicability."

Answer (score 0):

Since [Narrowing Primitive Conversions(§5.1.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.3) says that narrowing of `int` is done into `byte`, `short`, or `char`. So you need to cast the `int` to `byte` where you calling the method. Like this :

```
test.sum(1, (byte)2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve more with the primitive integer. Thus, everytime you write a value that can be an "integer" value, Java automatically wants to cast and thus treat it like an integer.

The converse of this is what happens when you try what you tried here. Java sees a value which can fit as an integer but for it to treat it as a byte, you need to explicitly tell. It's a bit like saying, OK, I know what I am doing and I do realize that casting a number to a byte has its limitations but I want you to do it anyway.